# Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:[10.2.1, 12.1.0)

Tags: firebase, gradle, build, onesignal

I want to share a problem that become a nightmare for me:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':OnlineHeadBall2@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:[10.2.1, 12.1.0).
```

When I try to build my project, I get an error on console:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':appName:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':appName:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:[10.2.1, 12.1.0).
     Required by:
         project :appName > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.9
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HyprMXMobile/Android-SDKs/master/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HyprMXMobile/Android-SDKs/master/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HyprMXMobile/Android-SDKs/master/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[10.2.1, 12.1.0).
     Required by:
         project :appName > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.9
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HyprMXMobile/Android-SDKs/master/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HyprMXMobile/Android-SDKs/master/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HyprMXMobile/Android-SDKs/master/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[10.2.1, 12.1.0).
     Required by:
         project :appName > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.9
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-base.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HyprMXMobile/Android-SDKs/master/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HyprMXMobile/Android-SDKs/master/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HyprMXMobile/Android-SDKs/master/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-base.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Error running command, return code: 1.
```

I feel that the suspicious in here is OneSignal. Therefore I apply [the workaround in here](https://share.getcloudapp.com/4gum4Ple) to OneSignal, but my apk that I recently build is crash on starting. So the workaround does not work for me.

My general gradle file is below:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is my app gradle file:

```
/** GENERATE CMAKEFILES.TXT FOR GAME CLASSES **/
file("../../Classes/cmake/CMakeLists.txt").withWriter("utf-8") { writer ->
    writer.writeLine("\n# APP NAME AUTOGENERATED CMAKELISTS FILE, DO NOT DELETE #\n")

    writer.writeLine("set(GAME_SOURCE")
    project.fileTree("../../Classes").matching {
        include "**/**.cpp"
        include "**/**.c"
    }.sort().forEach { file ->
        writer.writeLine("\t${file.path}")
    }
    writer.writeLine(")\n\n")

    writer.write("set(GAME_HEADER\n")
    project.fileTree("../../Classes").matching {
        include "**/**.hpp"
        include "**/**.h"
    }.sort().forEach { file ->
        writer.writeLine("\t${file.path}")
    }
    writer.writeLine(")\n\n")
}
/*********************************************/


buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}//onesignal
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.appName"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 111908

        versionName "1.119"
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "*****************************",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]


        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        }

        externalNativeBuild {
            if(PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'ndk-build') {
                ndkBuild {
                    targets 'appName'

                    def module_paths = [project.file("../../cocos2d").absolutePath,
                                        project.file("../../cocos2d/cocos").absolutePath,
                                        project.file("../../cocos2d/external").absolutePath]

                    arguments 'NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang'
                    arguments 'APP_PLATFORM=android-' + PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
                    arguments '-j' + Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()

                    if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
                        module_paths = module_paths.collect {it.replaceAll('\\\\', '/')}
                        arguments 'NDK_MODULE_PATH=' + module_paths.join(";")
                    } else {
                        arguments 'NDK_MODULE_PATH=' + module_paths.join(':')
                    }

                }
            } else if(PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'cmake') {
                cmake {
                    targets 'appName'
                    arguments "-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
                    cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -fsigned-char"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        java.srcDir "src"
        res.srcDir "res"
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']
        jni.srcDirs = []
        manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
        assets.srcDir "../../Resources"
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        if(PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'ndk-build') {
            ndkBuild {
                path "jni/Android.mk"
            }
        } else if (PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'cmake') {
            cmake {
                path "../../CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            def userHomePath = System.properties['user.home']
            def propertyFile = new File(userHomePath, ".gradle/gradle.properties") // Can be signing.properties as well
            if (propertyFile.canRead()){
                Properties props = new Properties()
                props.load(new FileInputStream(propertyFile))
                // Loading credentials from props
                storeFile file(props['RELEASE_STORE_FILE'])
                storePassword props['RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD']
                keyAlias props['RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS']
                keyPassword props['RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD']
            }
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = true
            zipAlignEnabled false
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments 'NDK_DEBUG=0'
                }
            }
        }

        debug {
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false // prevent fabric.io to generate id

            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments 'NDK_DEBUG=1'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /* 
    // This is required for the gradle automation.
    // Source https://medium.com/mindorks/how-did-i-automate-the-generation-of-release-apk-3e42b6540a4a
    TLDR;
    Also notice that I have added lintOptions which ignores errors at build time. This is needed for our automate script to work.
    If lintOptions are not disabled, it gives the error belov
    ▸ org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: /meta read: HEAD (position:END_TAG </HEAD>@2:32 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4b80c948)
    */
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {

    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }

    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    maven { url 'http://repo.admost.com:8081/artifactory/admost' }
    //maven { url 'http://repo.admost.com:8081/artifactory/test-before-publish' }

    maven { url 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HyprMXMobile/Android-SDKs/master' }
    maven { url 'https://vungle.bintray.com/vungle-android-beta' }
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
    maven { url "http://dl.appnext.com/" }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/pubnative/maven' }
}

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
}

rootProject.allprojects.each(){
    it.repositories {
        flatDir dirs: (projectDir.absolutePath+'/libs')
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation project(':libcocos2dx')

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    //'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.11.2, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.1'

    implementation 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.16.0'
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.+'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.11.1'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.1.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.19.5'

    // AMR
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:amr:2.0.7'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:admost:0.0.6.a16'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:admob-gt-17.2.0-adapter:1.0.2.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:adcolony:4.1.2.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:chartboost:7.5.0.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:facebook:5.6.1.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:hyprmx-adapter:5.0.1.a16'
    implementation 'com.hyprmx.android:HyprMX-SDK:5.0.1'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:ironsource:6.13.0.1.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:mintegral:10.2.1.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:ogury:4.3.7.a16'
    implementation 'net.pubnative:hybid.sdk:0.7.1'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:pubnative-adapter:0.7.1.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:qumpara:0.3.3.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:tapjoy:12.4.2.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:unity:3.4.0.a16'
    implementation 'com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.5.1'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:vungle-adapter:6.5.1.a16'


    implementation name: 'mcprime', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mcgoliath', ext: 'aar'
    implementation (name:'ADTUnityAdsAdapter3.0.1',ext:'aar')


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle Wrapper Properties File:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Do you have any idea to solve this issue? Please help me. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My teammate Erman solve this issue. I want to share with you the solution. I am going to share the gradle files that can be successfully build app. You should analyze differences between old and new ones.

**main gradle**

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
        }
    }

**app module gradle**

/** GENERATE CMAKEFILES.TXT FOR GAME CLASSES **/
file("../../Classes/cmake/CMakeLists.txt").withWriter("utf-8") { writer ->
    writer.writeLine("\n# APP NAME AUTOGENERATED CMAKELISTS FILE, DO NOT DELETE #\n")
    writer.writeLine("set(GAME_SOURCE")
    project.fileTree("../../Classes").matching {
        include "**/**.cpp"
        include "**/**.c"
    }.sort().forEach { file ->
        writer.writeLine("\t${file.path}")
    }
    writer.writeLine(")\n\n")
    writer.write("set(GAME_HEADER\n")
    project.fileTree("../../Classes").matching {
        include "**/**.hpp"
        include "**/**.h"
    }.sort().forEach { file ->
        writer.writeLine("\t${file.path}")
    }
    writer.writeLine(")\n\n")
}
/*********************************************/
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}//onesignal
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.4, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.appName"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 111908
        versionName "1.119"
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "*************************",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            if(PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'ndk-build') {
                ndkBuild {
                    targets 'appName'
                    def module_paths = [project.file("../../cocos2d").absolutePath,
                                        project.file("../../cocos2d/cocos").absolutePath,
                                        project.file("../../cocos2d/external").absolutePath]
                    arguments 'NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang'
                    arguments 'APP_PLATFORM=android-' + PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
                    arguments '-j' + Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
                    if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
                        module_paths = module_paths.collect {it.replaceAll('\\\\', '/')}
                        arguments 'NDK_MODULE_PATH=' + module_paths.join(";")
                    } else {
                        arguments 'NDK_MODULE_PATH=' + module_paths.join(':')
                    }
                }
            } else if(PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'cmake') {
                cmake {
                    targets 'appName'
                    arguments "-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
                    cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -fsigned-char"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        java.srcDir "src"
        res.srcDir "res"
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']
        jni.srcDirs = []
        manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
        assets.srcDir "../../Resources"
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        if(PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'ndk-build') {
            ndkBuild {
                path "jni/Android.mk"
            }
        } else if (PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'cmake') {
            cmake {
                path "../../CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            def userHomePath = System.properties['user.home']
            def propertyFile = new File(userHomePath, ".gradle/gradle.properties") // Can be signing.properties as well
            if (propertyFile.canRead()){
                Properties props = new Properties()
                props.load(new FileInputStream(propertyFile))
                // Loading credentials from props
                storeFile file(props['RELEASE_STORE_FILE'])
                storePassword props['RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD']
                keyAlias props['RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS']
                keyPassword props['RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD']
            }
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = true
            zipAlignEnabled false
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments 'NDK_DEBUG=0'
                }
            }
        }
        debug {
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false // prevent fabric.io to generate id
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments 'NDK_DEBUG=1'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /* 
    // This is required for the gradle automation.
    // Source https://medium.com/mindorks/how-did-i-automate-the-generation-of-release-apk-3e42b6540a4a
    TLDR;
    Also notice that I have added lintOptions which ignores errors at build time. This is needed for our automate script to work.
    If lintOptions are not disabled, it gives the error belov
    ▸ org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: /meta read: HEAD (position:END_TAG </HEAD>@2:32 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4b80c948)
    */
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.admost.com:8081/artifactory/admost' }
    //maven { url 'http://repo.admost.com:8081/artifactory/test-before-publish' }
    //maven { url 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HyprMXMobile/Android-SDKs/master' }
    maven { url 'https://vungle.bintray.com/vungle-android-beta' }
    //maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
    maven { url "http://dl.appnext.com/" }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/pubnative/maven' }
}
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
}
rootProject.allprojects.each(){
    it.repositories {
        flatDir dirs: (projectDir.absolutePath+'/libs')
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':libcocos2dx')
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.3'
    //'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.11.2, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.3'

    implementation 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.16.0'
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.+'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.11.2, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.19.5'
    // AMR
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:amr:2.0.7'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:admost:0.0.6.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:admob-gt-17.2.0-adapter:1.0.2.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:adcolony:4.1.2.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:chartboost:7.5.0.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:facebook:5.6.1.a16'
    //implementation 'com.admost.sdk:hyprmx-adapter:5.0.1.a16'
    //implementation 'com.hyprmx.android:HyprMX-SDK:5.0.1'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:ironsource:6.13.0.1.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:mintegral:10.2.1.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:ogury:4.3.7.a16'
    implementation 'net.pubnative:hybid.sdk:0.7.1'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:pubnative-adapter:0.7.1.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:qumpara:0.3.3.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:tapjoy:12.4.2.a16'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:unity:3.4.0.a16'
    implementation 'com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.5.1'
    implementation 'com.admost.sdk:vungle-adapter:6.5.1.a16'
    implementation name: 'mcprime', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mcgoliath', ext: 'aar'
    implementation (name:'ADTUnityAdsAdapter3.0.1',ext:'aar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```